# Triggered job timing out unexpectedly

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins job MASTER with a build step that triggers 3 other builds J1,J2, and J3 using "Trigger/call builds on other projects".  All 3 builds are listed in the same section (one blank separated by commas - "J2,J2,J3"), with "Block until the triggered projects finish their builds" checked.  J1 and J2 complete; after 20 minutes have elapsed, the build step ends with "Build timed out (after 20 minutes).  Marking the build as failed."  J3 actually runs to completion in 28 minutes (the MASTER log seems to say J3 is aborted, but J3 completes and is SUCCESSFUL.)

Where does this 20 minute time limit come from?  Is it configurable?

MASTER has a 60-minute timeout (Build Environment: "Elastic/300%/3/60/min-as-shortest=checked"), as do J1 and J2.  J3 has a 45 minute timeout.  All 3 jobs get their timeout indirectly (the only "Build Environment" setting is "Use build environment from another project".)

```
11:27:40 Run condition [Always] enabling perform for step [Trigger/call builds on other projects]
11:27:40 Waiting for the completion of J1
11:36:49 J1 #20 completed. Result was SUCCESS
11:36:49 Waiting for the completion of J2
11:36:49 J2 #16 completed. Result was SUCCESS
11:36:49 Waiting for the completion of J3
11:47:40 Build timed out (after 20 minutes). Marking the build as failed.
11:47:40 Build was aborted
```

Jenmins 2.74 on Windows Server 2012; Parameterized Trigger plugin 2.35.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although MASTER had a 60-minute timeout, it was an "elastic" timeout.

During job development, execution of the child jobs was temporarily suspended and there were three successful prior job completions that took less than 7 minutes.  With the "elastic" percentage set to 300%, the master job time limit was 20 minutes.

The child job is not what was being terminated; it was the master job that timed out.  That the log message appeared underneath the execution of a child job was merely a confusing, unfortunate coincidence.